# Google Sheets how do I strip out different values for multiple rows?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In Google Sheets, I'm working on eCommerce site redirects with 1000 rows of URLs that have a string that ends in **"?value"**.

If each string ends in **"?value"**, how can I strip out the question mark and everything following the question mark?

Example of column A:

https://www.example.com/text-text/text/text_text/detail/**?value=xyz**

https://www.example.com/text-text/text/text_text/detail/**?value=xyz-123**

https://www.example.com/detail/**?value=abcdef-1**

This is an example of the desired result:

https://www.example.com/text-text/text/text_text/detail/

https://www.example.com/text-text/text_text/detail/

https://www.example.com/detail/

**Value** character lengths differ for each of the 1000 products.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that https://www.example.com/text-text/text/text_text/detail/?value/ is in A1...

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(A1, "?"), 1, 1)
```

... will give you "https://www.example.com/text-text/text/text_text/detail/"

Comment: I apologize I may not have been clear enough the first time - I updated my question, is your answer still relevant to the problem?

Comment: @HannaE. Yes, just change the index value

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your original URLs are in A2:A, try entering the following formula in B1 (or an otherwise empty Column B):

```
=ArrayFormula({"Extracted URL";IF(A2:A="",, REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(.+\/).*\?value"))})
```

Comment: I apologize I may not have been clear enough the first time - I updated my question, is your answer still relevant to the problem?

Comment: Hanna, it is still not entirely clear what format your URLS will have (e.g., do the double asterisks in your examples denote wildcards meaning "any text or none might go here"?). But I have edited my formula to work with what I now believe you are looking for.